# How do you clear the offline cache for web apps in Safari?

Tags: web-applications, html, safari, offline

I know in Chrome you can clear offline apps by typing this address

chrome://appcache-internals/

Does safari 5.0+ have something similar?

Please note that CTRL+ALT+E will not remove offline web apps from the cache.

Comment: In the menu bar, go to Safari > Empty Cache….

Comment: Safari -> Empty Cache seems to clear some other cache, not any HTML5 manifest cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OS X the Safari cache manifest database can be found in

```
/var/folders/XX/xxxxxx/-Caches-/com.apple.Safari/ApplicationCache.db
```

where *X/x* is random characters.  (You'll find one set of random characters for each user on your computer; you only need to worry about the path that corresponds to your account.) Delete ApplicationCache.db and restart Safari. (The .db file will regenerate when Safari encounters a site with a cache manifest.)

The easiest way to get at this file is to run the following command in Terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

and then force a restart of Finder.  When you're done run

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```

and restart Finder again.

I found the seed of this answer [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=66435).

Comment: On Safari 6.0.5 under OS X 10.8.4 the path is slightly different, `/var/folders/XX/xxxxxx/C/com.apple.Safari/ApplicationCache.db` (`C` instead of `-Caches-`)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to empty the application cache for a single site without disturbing other sites' caches, you can:

1. [Enable the Develop menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW1).
2. In the Develop menu, check "Disable Caches."
3. Refresh the page.
4. Uncheck "Disable Caches" to resume normal operation.

Note: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, Empty Caches, as noted in the question, does nothing to this effect.

Comment: Unfortunately that only seems to disable the normal browser cache instead of the app files in the cache manifest. 
Other answers involving ApplicationCache.db work.

Answer (score 3):

Close Safari, delete the ApplicationCache.db file and start Safari again and your AppCache is cleared.

On a Windows machine the Safari Offline Application Cache resides here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Apple Computer\Safari\ApplicationCache.db
```

Where **Administrator** is the name of the logged on user.

In Windows 7, it's

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\ApplicationCache.db
```

Note that `AppData` is a hidden folder.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Developer menu > Empty cache.

[image: screenshot]

- **Make sure you restart the browser** since it sometimes requires in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Most times a simple force refresh will do the trick, you can accomplish this with the following key combinations: 
On the PC: Command + R 
On the Mac: Apple + R

[image: HOW TO CLEAR SAFARI CACHE ?]

[HOW TO CLEAR SAFARI CACHE ?](http://downuptime.com/how-to/clear-safari-cache.html)